# ListBoxFor add data attribute to each option element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MultiSelectList that I am currently using to create a ListBoxFor in my view. On my ViewModel I have an additional property on each of the items in the list that I would like to expose in the HTML for client side manipulation.

I have a checkbox above this list. When a user clicks the checkbox only `data-x="true"` items should show in this list. If the user does not click the checkbox, all items are shown (`data-x="true"` and `data-x="false"`). This logic is done client side each time the checkbox it changed

I am assuming the best way to do this would be to add a data-* attribute to each of the option elements. How exactly would I go about doing this? I am thinking an HTMLHelper method would be needed to extend the functionality of ListBoxfor but I am not sure where to get started, or if this is even the best way to go about this?

Comment: In order to use a HtmlHelper extension method you would need to create you own (say) `SelectListItemWithAttribute` class and then create you own extension method based on rewriting the bulk of the code in [System.Web.Mvc.SelectExtensions](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) class. Why would you want to add `data-*` attributes to `<option>` elements (I suspect you have the classic X-Y problem)?

Comment: I have a checkbox above this list. When a user clicks the checkbox only data-x="true" items should show in this list. If the user does not click the checkbox, all items are shown (data-x="true" and data-x="false"). This logic is done client side each time the checkbox it changed.

Comment: Then that should be done by using ajax to call a server method (passing the value of the checkbox) and returning the options to populate the dropdownlist, or by storing an array of your objects in a javascript array and using javascript to build your options based on the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to generate `<option>` elements with a `data=*` attribute, you would need to create you own class based on `SelectListItem` with additional properties for the attributes, and then generate you own HtmlHelper extension method based on the code in the [System.Web.Mvc.SelectExtensions](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) class.

A far easier way to handle this would be to pass collection you use to build the `SelectList` to the view, assign it to a javascript array and then use javascript/jquery to handle the checkbox `.click()` event and rebuild the list of options in the `<select>` element. In your case, it could simply be a case of hiding/showing items based on the value of the checkbox.

For example, if you have a view to select a product, and include a checkbox to limit that selection to only locally made products, your models might be

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool UseLocalProductOnly { get; set }
    public int SelectedProduct{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> LocalProducts { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocalProduct { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
var products = db.Products;
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel()
{
    ProductList = new SelectList(products, "ID", "Name"),
    LocalProducts = products.Where(x => x.IsLocalProduct).Select(x => x.ID)
}
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UseLocalProductOnly)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProduct, Model.ProductList)

<script>
    var localProducts = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.LocalProducts))
    var select = $('#SelectedProduct');
    var options = select.children('option');
    $('#UseLocalProductOnly').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // reset the selected option if it would otherwise be hidden
            if ($.inArray(Number(select.val()), localProducts) === -1) {
                select.val(localProducts[0]);
            }
            // hide options that are not local products
            $.each(options, function () {
                if ($.inArray(Number($(this).val()), localProducts) === -1) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // show all options
            productOptions.show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could use `.prop('disabled', true);` (or `false`) to enable or disable options rather that hiding them.